# How to create a visual data table in R to quickly screen the data visually

Tags: r

I have a following data set in txt form:

```
        Column1 Column2 Column3 etc
        A1 5 7
        A2 4 2
        ..
        A12 5 4
        B1 2 9
        B2 2 8
        ..
        B12 11 5
        ..
        H1 0 3
        H2 4 54
        ..
        H12 4 31
```

I would like to create a visual data table with A through H rows by 12 columns, with each cell filled with a corresponding value (value from column 2 or 3)  and gradient colored (like a heat map) based on its value. What is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with `dplyr` and `tidyr` for data wrangling and `gt` for visualization:

Note that `"Column2" is specified in`values_from`, but you could change that to visualize other columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(dt)
library(scales)
data %>% 
  separate(1, into = c("Column1","Name"),
           sep = "(?<=[A-Z])(?=\\d)") %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = 1, names_from = "Name",
              values_from = "Column2") %>%
  gt() %>%
  data_color(columns = 2:13, 
             colors = col_numeric(palette = c("green","yellow","red"),
                                  domain = c(10,1000)))
```

[image]
**Sample Data**

```
set.seed(3)  
data <- data.frame(Column1 = paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:8],each=12),rep(1:12,time=8)),sapply(c(10,20),function(x){round(runif(12*8,x,x*100),0)}))
names(data) <- paste0("Column",1:3)
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what im looking for! One complication to my problem - sometimes these text files will have certain cells missing, for instance one file might only have these cells containing values A2 --> H2 and A3--H3 column values.. In this case for empty cells id just like to display empty/non-colored cells. With this code im getting : Error: All column or row indices given must be present in `data_tbl`. I suppose its looking for a fully populated table with all values present A1 --H12. Can this be modified to still display "non-complete" / partial tables? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, this approach can easily be modified to replace `NA` with `0` for example. If you provide a sample of your data with `dput(data)` as **an edit** to your original question I can help.